# Linq query correct way

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want a list of people who share the same first Name, but have birth year either before 1960 or after 1970.

It is just a practice query, i was working with intersect, through which i was getting only name, but what if i wanted the whole object of person.

I tried this one, which is working.

```
using Chapter01Samples;

var contacts = Contact.SampleData();
var callLog = CallLog.SampleData();

var result = from contact in contacts
             group contact by contact.FirstName into person
             where person.Any( c => c.DateOfBirth.Year > 1970) 
                               && person.Any(c => c.DateOfBirth.Year < 1960)
             select person;
```

But if there is a better query, i would like to know

EDIT: If there are 2 people named Adam, and one has birth year 58 and one has 72, then only i should receive both objects. Same name should exist in both the category.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you just need to reverse your `where` and `group by` clauses. Filter first, then group:

```
var result = from contact in contacts
             where contact.DateOfBirth.Year > 1970 ||
                   contact.DateOfBirth.Year < 1960
             group contact by contact.FirstName;
```

Note the change from `&&` to `||`, so that we only collect people who were born either before 1960 *or* after 1970.

If this isn't what you want, please give more details. In particular, if you're trying to find "people born before 1960 who share a first name with at least one person born after 1970" then I would split it into a few stages. First filter and group the users, so we have people born before 1960 grouped by first name, and people born before 1970 grouped by first name. You can then perform an inner join on those groups, and the result for any pair of groups with the same key (first name) is just the concatenation of the members of the two groups.

```
// No offence intended by these names...
var oldGroups = contacts.Where(contact => contact.DateOfBirth.Year < 1960)
                        .GroupBy(p => p.FirstName);
var youngGroups = contacts.Where(contact => contact.DateOfBirth.Year > 1970)
                          .GroupBy(p => p.FirstName);
var query = oldGroups.Join(youngGroups, og => og.Key, yg => yg.Key,
                           (og, yg) => og.Concat(yg));
```

Comment: doesnt this statement contact.DateOfBirth.Year > 1970 && contact.DateOfBirth.Year < 1960 means the dob of the same person should be both >1970 and <1960, which is not possible

Comment: sorry, that was for the previous comment, in the current scenario, it would give me names even if there is only one person whose with dob>1970 or <1960...moreover, if there are 2 people , both >1970, they will be included

Comment: @ZaidBinIrfan: Yes, it would. It sounds like you haven't explained your requirements properly. It would help if you could provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: @ZaidBinIrfan: I've edited my answer based on what I *think* you might want.

Comment: @Jon...Thanks, that gets me the same output and yes i should have put my requirement in detail. So which one would you suggest, your solution sounds more correct, mine was shorter to write but i am not sure how many statements it performs.

Comment: I just checked out, your query gave result in 00:00:00.0012417 which is 50% faster than mine 00:00:00.0023435

Comment: @ZaidBinIrfan: I'd be more interested in clarity - and personally I think mine is clearer. It's a close representation of what you'd probably do if you were performing this manually (e.g. with contact cards).

Answer (score 1):

```
var contacts = Chapter01Samples.Contact.SampleData();

var query = contacts.Where(c => c.DateOfBirth.Year > 1970 || c.DateOfBirth.Year < 1960)
                    .GroupBy(c => c.FirstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use Datatable or dataset then its would be like
`dataTable.Select("Your simple where clause and other clauses")`
or if you use
`dataSet.Table[0].Select("Your simple where clause and other clauses")`